# point the IE browsers to standard mode testing in native browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

1. I tried to point the IE browsers to standard mode...
2. but its not working..
3. providing my code below...
4. can you tell me what mistake i am doing..
5. even i included the meta tag even included doctype
6. i am testing in native ie9 browsers...

I amusing sass and backbone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]>--><html class="no-js ie html" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: "its not working" — How do you know? What behaviour do you get and what behaviour do you expect?

Comment: First, how do you know it's not working?  What mode are you in?  Second, your Content-Type attribute must be first in the head tag, followed by X-UA-Compatible.